# Retrieving and checking a password in python with a csv file

Tags: python, regex, email, csv, line

I'm attempting to write a code which asks for an email and password (not for any particular purpose) and checks them against a csv file which contains several lines. Each line contains an email and password along with some made-up customer details. I'm trying to write a code which accepts an email address and password (5 - 12 characters long), then searches the file for the line containing both the email and password and prints the entire line (including customer details). Here is my code so far (some of the indentations might look a bit odd here, but are actually just a result of indenting for the code block):

```
import csv
import re
import sys

f = open('A453_datafile_4_Mat 4 Data File.csv', 'r').read()

print("Welcome to our website! To access your customer details, we first require you to sign in. ")
print("")
email = input ("Email address: ")
if re.match("\A(?P<name>[\w\-_]+)@(?P<domain>[\w\-_]+).(?P<toplevel>[\w]+)\Z",email,re.IGNORECASE):
print('')
else:
    email = input("Sorry, this isn't a valid email address! Try again: ")
    if re.match("\A(?P<name>[\w\-_]+)@(?P<domain>[\w\-_]+).(?P<toplevel>[\w]+)\Z",email,re.IGNORECASE):
        print('')
    else:
        print("You have entered your email incorrectly two times. The program will now terminate." )
    sys.exit() #ends program

password = input ("Password: ")
if re.match("\A(?P<name>[\w\-_]+)\Z",password,re.IGNORECASE): 
    print('')
else:
   password = input("Sorry, this isn't a valid password! Try again: ")
   if re.match("\A(?P<name>[\w\-_]+)\Z",password,re.IGNORECASE):
        print('')
   else:
        print("You have entered your password incorrectly two times. The program will now terminate." )
        sys.exit() #ends program


details = [line for line in f.split('\n') if email in line] and [line for line in f.split('\n') if password in line]

if details == []:
   print("Sorry, your email or password is invalid.")
else:
   print("Thank you! Here are your customer details: ")
   print("")
   details = str(details).strip('[]')
   print(details)
```

I'm having problems with this line, as the 'and' doesn't seem to work how I would like it to:

```
details = [line for line in f.split('\n') if email in line] and [line for line in f.split('\n')
```

If I enter a deliberately wrong password (e.g. the letter 'x'), and it happens to exist on another line, it will print that line despite the fact that it doesn't contain the email address.

Here is an example of this:

> Welcome to our website! To access your customer details, we first require you to sign in.
>
> Email address: ojones@coldmail.net
>
> Password: **x**
>
> Thank you! Here are your customer details:
>
> 'miguel5@bluebell.net,happy3,Miguel,Santos,45 Vine Avenue,Oxford,O**X**7 3RF'

Although it works with the correct password:

> Welcome to our website! To access your customer details, we first require you to sign in.
>
> Email address: ojones@coldmail.net
>
> Password: ocrabc
>
> Thank you! Here are your customer details:
>
> 'ojones@coldmail.net,ocrabc,Oliver,Jones,53 Vale House,Portsmouth,P03 2TD'

And also this regular expression, as I can't work out how to limit the password length to 5 - 12 characters (I'm new to regex and haven't been taught how to use it):

```
if re.match("\A(?P<name>[\w\-_]+)\Z",password,re.IGNORECASE)
```

I suspect that fixing this may mostly fix the former problem (unless someone knows the contents of the file), although some help with that would be appreciated if possible.

There may be other problems that I haven't picked up on, but as far as I know that's it.

I know this question is very long, so thank you for taking the time to read it, and any answers would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Er -- don't store passwords in plain text...

Comment: don't mind me asking, why no database?

Comment: @Jesse W at Z - They're not real passwords, all the info is made up for the purpose of this program.

Comment: @StefanNch - Database? Do I need one?

Comment: You must work for Sony.

Comment: @AnyaAlstreim You know best mate! It was a simple recommendation, because reinventing code is bad. Then again, I've been wrong before!

Answer (score 1):

Long question with simple answer. Do not use boolean operation 'and' for list concatenation. Use + and it will produce correct list. What 'and' do - it casts each operand to boolean True/False, and if both list are non-empty - return last of them. Otherwise it returns [] (never happens in your case).

Comment: Thank you! I haven't used and before and I thought it might be more appropriate than + in this case, clearly I should try both next time!

Answer (score 0):

What your code is currently doing is looping over the file twice: each [line for line in f.split()] is a separate loop. The first loop gets the list of lines where the email matches and the second gets the list of lines where the password matches.

Then you're combining the two lists using the 'and' operator. Python allows you to do that, and the result of this will be True if both of the lists are not empty and False otherwise. Since you're trying to compare the result of the operation with [], the comparison will always fail.

A correct version of what you're trying to do is to have a single loop and check both conditions at once, which Python list comprehensions allow you to do:

```
[line for line in f.split() if email in line and password in line]
```

However, since this is a substring check, this will match when the user has entered a part of the password correctly, which is normally not what you want when checking passwords. Instead, you should check the entire string:

```
line.startswith(email + "," + password + ",")
```

Comment: Thank you, this was really helpful. I wasn't sure how to check the entire string.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple implemention to search a CSV file for a specific string(s):

```
f = open('A453_datafile_4_Mat 4 Data File.csv', 'r').read() 
rows = re.split('\n', f.decode())

for index, row in enumerate(rows):
    cells = row.split(',')
    if ('USER_EMAIL_HERE' in cells) and ('USER_PASSWORD_HERE' in cells):
        #Do stuff here
```

I haven't tested this, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cleaned-up version:

```
import csv
from collections import namedtuple
from itertools import repeat
import re
import sys

EMAIL_REG    = re.compile("^([\w\-_]+@[\w\-_]+\.[\w]+)$", re.IGNORECASE)
PASSWORD_REG = re.compile("^([\w\-_]{5,12})$", re.IGNORECASE)
PASSWORD_CSV = 'A453_datafile_4_Mat 4 Data File.csv'

# define a User type
#   (the field names should match the columns from the .csv file)
User = namedtuple("User", ["email", "password", "firstname", "lastname", "address", "city", "postalcode"])
# prettier output
User.__str__ = lambda self: "{} {}: {} ({} {}, {})".format(self.firstname, self.lastname, self.email, self.address, self.city, self.postalcode)

def all_users_from_csv(fname, **kwargs):
    """
    Return an iterable of Users from the specified csv file
    """
    with open(fname) as in_file:
        for row in csv.reader(in_file, **kwargs):
            yield User(row)

def match_user(users, email, password):
    """
    Return the first user in users who matches the specified email and password;
      on failure, return None
    """
    for user in users:
        if user.email == email and user.password == password:
            return user
    return None

def input_match(prompt, reg, max_tries=None):
    """
    Prompt for input that matches reg;
      on success, return first match group
      on failure, try again (up to max_tries times, if specified)
      on max_tries failures, return None
    """
    if max_tries is None:
        # not specified - repeat forever
        tries = repeat(None)
    else:
        # repeat specified number of times
        tries = range(max_tries)

    for i in tries:
        s = input(prompt)
        m = reg.match(s)
        if m:
            return m.groups(0)

    # if max_tries exceeded
    return None

def do_signin():
    email = input_match("Email address: ", EMAIL_REG, 2)
    if email is None:
        print("You did not enter a valid email address. Good-bye!")
        return None

    password = input_match("Password: ", PASSWORD_REG, 2)
    if email is None:
        print("You did not enter a valid password. Good-bye!")
        return None

    users = all_users_from_csv(PASSWORD_CSV)
    return match_user(users, email, password)

def main():
    print("Welcome to our website! To access your customer details, we first require you to sign in.\n")

    user = do_signin()
    if user is None:
        print("Sorry, your email or password is invalid.")
    else:
        print("Thank you! Here are your customer details:\n")
        print(user)

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

And some comments:

1. Note that each time you want to match a user, it has to compare (up to) every line in the .csv file; this is slow and wasteful. Pretty much any database would allow you to index on the email and password fields, making this much more efficient.
2. I split the code into individual functions; each function is simple and has only one specific purpose. Named constants, good function names, docstrings, and comments - they all make your program easier to understand, test, and modify later.